# Node/Passport: Display different page when logged in

Tags: express, passport.js

How do I display a different homepage once the user has logged in?

Following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) (so new at this). Once a person has logged in, I would like to pass the user info to the homepage, and display a completely different homepage to the page a non-logged in person sees.

How do I do this? A sort of:

`If a user is logged in 
    display this, and username <username>
else
    display this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from the tutorial you must have learned this much that when you have a user succesfully logged in then on any route you have `req.user` accessible. Conversely absense of it can be considered that a user has not (yet) logged in. Essentially providing you with a boolean logic to separate the two scenarios which you can then use to, for example display different versions of the homepage:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if(req.user)
        res.render('logged-in-homepage.jade');
    else
        res.render('normal-homepage.jade');
});
```